# Not receiving forgot password emails after admin_create_user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a problem for which I have  been hammering for days at now.

I am creating a new user through Lambda at Cognito programmatically with the `admin_create_user()` command. The user status after creation is set to **FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD** by cognito. This is where the problem starts.

The newly created user is sent an email with a temporary password. So my thought was to have that user login like normal after which he/she will be forced to reset (forgot) the password. So I call the `forgot_password()` command.

The logs outputs the following:

> START RequestId:  Version: $LATEST
>
> [INFO]   2020-03-17T21:58:46.172Z    RECEIVED THE FOLLOWING EMAIL ADDRESS: myemailaddress+testuser@gmail.com
>
> [INFO]   2020-03-17T21:58:46.516Z        COGNITO FORGOT_PASSWORD RESPONSE: {'CodeDeliveryDetails': {'Destination': 'm***@g***.com', 'DeliveryMedium': 'EMAIL', 'AttributeName': 'email'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Tue, 17 Mar 2020 21:58:46 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '104', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': '}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
>
> END RequestId:
>
> REPORT RequestId:  Duration: 359.45 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 78 MB  Init Duration: 302.80 ms

To me it seems Lambda successfully executed the Cognito `forgot_password()` call. Cognito has been setup to send emails through SES with a fully verified domain name setup, including SPF and DKIM (all green showing in the console). I have setup bounce, complaints and deliveries SNS topics too.

However, somehow I never get the email. Nor do I get the  delivery report.

At first I was suspecting the ‘+’ character within the email address  being the problem, but I tried a normal email address too without luck. Next I thought that creating the user with `admin_create_user()` without confirming the email would be the problem, but even setting `email_verified` to `True` wont make a difference. I also tried to set the Cognito default email method (so no SES use) with the same result.

I am lost. Do you guys have any tips on how I can track this further down?

Note: The client app has been setup without a Secret key, so the SecretHash param is not required.